# Tomcat startup batch issue

Tags: java, xampp, tomcat8

Can anyone please explain the below problem.

I'm using **tomcat 8**  and when I'm trying to start *startup.bat* file, the command prompt is opening and closing immediately just like blinking. However in the past while I'm working with java programs it worked fine but recently I installed Xampp and there in it again tomcat is downloaded "**C:\xampp\tomcat**". The same problem comes here in this folder as well, when I try to run *startup.bat* file. But when I use "**XAMPP control panel**" to start the Tomcat its able to get start and I'm getting "localhost:8080" start page in the browser.

The connector port for both tomcats are 8080 and I tried with changing the port number in tomcat 8 but no use. There should not be 2 tomcat servers in a single system? If not, why? (I've not installed them, both are in C drive)

I want to work with java servlet programs now.So I need use of tomcat. I've set below environment user varibles:

> JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65;
>
> path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

Please suggest the solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to open command line tool, and run startup.bat from there and post output here.

Comment: I think your question is very similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23358984/4137880

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the tomcat log to find some clues, it is in log folder of your tomcat installation folder. Maybe you have missed some startup variable in start.bat for your new installed things.

BTW, if you want to keep seeing what happened in startup, try to run startup.bat in a command line console, but not double click it through your mouse. It will continue on generating log output in that console.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\tomcat8\bin>startup.bat
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

Comment: @Denis Below is the command promt shows:
>Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

>C:\tomcat8\bin>startup.bat
>The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>This environment variable is needed to run this program

I added environment variable : 
JRE_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65

But no use. I've two folders in C:\Program Files\Java - jdk1.8.0_65 and jre1.8.0_65. The jdk1.8.0_65 contains again jre folder in it. Is this any problem?

Comment: you can "echo %JRE_HOME%" in console before you run the startup.bat to make sure if it is correctly set. If it still not works, you should check the startup.bat to see where this JRE_HOME env var is set and used to find the root cause for it.