# Tomcat no longer recognizing Java environment variables

Tags: java, tomcat

I never had problems running Tomcat before, and I don't think I changed anything. I've included pictures to show that things seem to be set up correctly as far as I can tell.

```
D:\>echo %CATALINA_HOME%
D:\JavaEEstuff\apache-tomcat-8.0.30

D:\>echo %JRE_HOME%
D:\Java\jre1.8.0_102

D:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
D:\Java\jdk102

D:\>%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat

The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correct
This environment variable is needed to run this program

D:\>%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat start
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correct
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDVQn.png)

[jre folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFqlQ.png)

Comment: what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492878/jre-home-variable-missing-with-tomcat-win7

Comment: Do you have a `bin\setenv.bat`? Is `D:\Java\jre1.8.1_102` a sane JRE?